# Dirichlet eigenvalue problem with disjoint domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded with $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 = \emptyset$. Consider the following eigenvalue problem: Find $(u,\lambda) \in H^1_0(\Omega_1) \times H^1_0(\Omega_2) \times \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
\begin{equation}
a(u,v) := \sum^2_{i=1}\int_{\Omega_i}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \lambda \sum^2_{i=1}\int_{\Omega_i}u v, \hspace{2mm} \forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega_1) \times H^1_0(\Omega_2).
\end{equation}
I want to write the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunctions $u_n$ of this problem with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the dirichlet eigenvalue problem on $\Omega_i$,$i =1,2$. So my approach would be to state: Find $(u,\lambda) \in H^1_0(\Omega_i) \times \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega_i}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \lambda \int_{\Omega_i}u v, \hspace{2mm} \forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega_i).
\end{equation}
Let then $(u_{i,n})_n \subset H^1_0(\Omega_i)$ be the eigenvectors of the corresponding eigenvalues $(\lambda_{i,n})_n \subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$ of the dirichlet problem on $\Omega_i$ for $i = 1,2$. Since $u_{i,n} \in H^1_0(\Omega_i)$ we can extend the eigenfunctions to $\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$ s.t. $u_{1,n}$ vanishes on $\Omega_2$ and
the same for $u_{2,n}$. Then we get with $u_n := (u_{1,n},u_{2,n})^T \in H^1_0(\Omega_1) \times H^1_0(\Omega_2)$ and $v = (v_1,v_2) \in H^1_0(\Omega_1) \times H^1_0(\Omega_2)$ by extending each coordinate of $v$ to $\Omega_i$,$i = 1,2$ by $0$
\begin{align}
\sum^2_{i=1}\int_{\Omega_i}\nabla u_n \cdot \nabla v &= \int_{\Omega_1}\nabla u_{1,n} \cdot \nabla v_1 + \nabla u_{2,n} \cdot \nabla v_2 +  \int_{\Omega_2}\nabla u_{1,n} \cdot \nabla v_1 + \nabla u_{2,n} \cdot \nabla v_2 \\
&= \int_{\Omega_1}\nabla u_{1,n} \cdot \nabla v_1 + \int_{\Omega_2}\nabla u_{2,n} \cdot \nabla v_2 \\
&= \lambda_{1,n} \int_{\Omega_1}u_{1,n}v_1 + \lambda_{2,n} \int_{\Omega_2}u_{2,n}v_2 \\
&= \lambda_{1,n} \int_{\Omega_1}u_{1,n}v_1 + u_{2,n} v_2 + \lambda_{2,n} \int_{\Omega_2}u_{1,n} v_1 + u_{2,n}v_2.
\end{align}
Now I don't understand how one gets the eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ with corresponding eigenvector $u_n$ out of $\lambda_{1,n}$ and $\lambda_{2,n}$ from the dirichlet eigenvalue problems on the different domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. I am not sure if this approach is even the right one. Maybe the eigenvalues are the same but I can't seem to prove this.
I would be thankful for any hint.

Edit: The idea is to look at
\begin{equation}
a((u_1,0),(v_1,v_2)) = \int_{\Omega_1}\nabla u_1 \nabla v_1 = \lambda_{1,n} \int_{\Omega_1}u_1 v_1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
a((0,u_2),(v_1,v_2)) = \int_{\Omega_2}\nabla u_2 \nabla v_2 = \lambda_{2,n} \int_{\Omega_2}u_2 v_2
\end{equation}
then the eigenvalue problem on $\Omega_1$ gives the eigenvectors $(u_{1,n},0)$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_{1,n}$ and the same goes for the eigenvalues $\lambda_{2,n}$ and eigenvectors $(0,u_{2,n})$ for the problem on $\Omega_2$. So the all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues are a composition of eigenvectors of these forms

Comment: It might be worthwhile working through the simpler case $u''(x) = \lambda u(x)$ on both $(-2, -1)$ and $(1, 5)$ subject to $u(-2) = u(-1) = u(1) = u(5) = 0$.